# A problem of convergence of Levy measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

We say that $\mu$ is a Levy measure in $\mathbb R^n$ if:
$$\int_{|x|< 1} |x|^2 d\mu < \infty, \quad \int_{|x|\geq1} d\mu < \infty  $$

Let $(\mu_n)$ be a sequence of Levy measures and $\mu$ another Levy measure. Suppose that:
$$\mu_n(E)\to \mu(E), \quad ( E \in \mathcal C_\mu, \, 0 \notin \bar E)$$
where $C_\mu$ is the class of continuity sets of $\mu$ and $\bar E$ the clousure of $E$.

How to show the following?
$$\int_E |x|^2 d \mu_n \to \int_E |x|^2 d \mu, \quad \forall E \subset D=\{x \in \mathbb R^n :  \,\, |x|<1\} $$

Any help?

Comment: "$\int_E |x|^2 d\mu_n \to \int_E |x|^2 d\mu$" does not hold.